# Update sObject from Batch Apex when the sObject's other custom field value is invalid

Tags: apex, batch, sobject

So we have a situation where we have some custom sObjects that have some custom fields that are picklists.

From time to time an Apex batch job runs to update picklists in `Custom_Field_1__c`.

Now we add a pair of other fields such as `Custom_Field_2__c` and `Custom_Field__3__c`, also picklists.
Then we add any manner of validatable dependency - e.g. setting `Custom_Field_2__c` to be `required`; or adding dependency between the two; or adding some custom Apex trigger or validation rule.
We then create some records, and break the validation by, e.g.

- Deleting the picklist value if we made a field required
- Breaking dependency between our field
- Any custom logic in the trigger/validation rule

(The point I am making that it DOES NOT matter why validation fails, I need a solution/workaround that would work with any and all).

Now my batch job that was happily operating on `Custom_Field_1__c` is failing because of validation errors for the other two custom fields.

How can I update my original field in a batch job IGNORING any other validation errors because they pertain to unrelated business processes?

Comment: Are you essentially asking how do you bypass database level validations?

Comment: @NickCook yup, especially the ones that I am not aware of in my Managed Package (e.g. stuff admins create later)